# String within function in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function, concatenation

I want to write a function in python that reads in my data. Outside this function, something like this works

```
model = open_ncfile('/data/BAF_2001-2013_model.nc')
lat_model = model.variables['lat'][:]
lon_model = model.variables['lon'][:]
data = model.variables['var'][0,:,:]
```

How can I put this into a function?

```
def plot(model, lat, lon, var):
    model = open_ncfile('/data/BAF_2001-2013_model.nc')
    lat_model = model.variables['lat'][:]
    lon_model = model.variables['lon'][:]
    model = model.variables['var'][0,:,:]
```

I guess the basic question here is how I concatenate strings within a function in python,  so if I call

```
plot(model1, lat1, lon1, var1)
```

my function would yield

```
model1 = open_ncfile('/data/BAF_2001-2013_model1.nc')
lat_model1 = model1.variables['lat1'][:]
lon_model1 = model1.variables['lon1'][:]
model1 = model1.variables['var1'][0,:,:]
```

So I can call the function with different models that have different names for their variable names. Couldn't find it anywhere!
Thanks :)

Comment: `return model.variables['var'][0,:,:]` ?

Comment: I think you should google the definition of "concatenate"

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how arguments work in python. As far as I can tell, you have a function `plot(model, lat, long, var)`. If you call it with the arguments `model1`, etc (eg `plot(model1, lat1, lon1, var1)`), those objects are what the function will operate on. Unless you're wondering about the file name?

Comment: If I call plot(model1, lat1, lon1, var1), python will interpret it as            /scratch/local1/m300481/Data/Observation/SF1/BAF_2001-2013_model.nc', but I want /scratch/local1/m300481/Data/Observation/SF1/BAF_2001-2013_model1.nc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but I suppose you basically want to dynamically fetch a model and retrieve its data, so this should do the trick:

```
def plot(model_name, lat_name, lon_name, var_name):
    model = open_ncfile('/data/BAF_2001-2013_{}.nc'.format(model_name))
    lat = model.variables[lat_name][:]
    lon = model.variables[lon_name][:]
    var = model.variables[var_name][0,:,:]
    return (model, lat, lon, var)
```

And then you can:

```
model, lat, lon, data = plot('model', 'lat', 'lon', 'var')
model1, lat1, lon1, data1 = plot('model1', 'lat1', 'lon1', 'var1')
model42, lat42, lon42, data42 = plot('model42', 'lat42', 'lon42', 'var42')
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea in this answer to include the option of doing string concatenation as well:

model = open_ncfile('/data/BAF_2001-2013_' + model_name + '.nc')

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had some trouble to make my point but this works perfectly!